# Google App Engine Project Error

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I installed the google app engine sdk and plugin and every time I'm trying to save a java file my IDE (Eclipse Kepler) shows me an error window: "Java Virtual Machine Launcher - Could not find the main class com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance. Program will exit".

In the console there is also a message:

"java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/tools/enhancer/Enhance : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main"

It happens only in GAP and GWT projects...simple web or java projects are fine.

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the JDK version that you have setup in your Eclipse settings? What is the App Engine SDK version?

Comment: jdk1.6.0_26 and the latest appengine sdk

Comment: The latest SDK 1.8.8 expects that you move to JDK 1.7. Please try with the latest JDK and see if the problem goes away. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/

Comment: Wow...I was so frustrated...It works! Thank you very very much for the fast answer!